# page not scrolling correctly

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

I am attempting to load a local text file in my WP7 application (a privacy statement) for quick reference if the user wishes to review the statement. I have tried a couple different ways to load the text file, both of which work, except the page does not scroll down as it should based upon default behavior. In attempting to scroll down, the page mimics the end of scrolling up on a page functionality, ergo it acts as if the top of the page has been reached.

attempt 1 - load text file into scrollviewer

XAML

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="PrivacyStatementScrollViewer">

        </ScrollViewer>            
    </Grid>
```

C#

```
var resourceStream = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri  ("Content/About/license.txt", UriKind.Relative));
        if (resourceStream != null)
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resourceStream.Stream);
            string x = sr.ReadToEnd();
            PrivacyStatementScrollViewer.Content = x;
        }
```

Attempt 2 - load text file into textblock

XAML

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="PrivacyStatementScrollViewer">
            <TextBlock x:Name="PrivacyStatementTextBlock" Margin="12,0,12,0" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
        </ScrollViewer>            
    </Grid>
```

C#

```
var resourceStream = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("Content/About/license.txt", UriKind.Relative));
        if (resourceStream != null)
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resourceStream.Stream);
            string x = sr.ReadToEnd();
            PrivacyStatementTextBlock.Text = x;
        }
```

I have never encountered any such functionality like this before, and was hoping someone might have come across the same issue or would have suggestions on how to fix this scrolling issue!?

Comment: issue might be the hieght of your scroll viewer. check it.

Comment: @NOOB i've tried changing the height with no luck. Also I've attempted the first answer below with no luck either?

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced your 2nd code and by modifing xaml it works. here is my code:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="PrivacyStatementScrollViewer" Margin="-4,4,4,8">
        <TextBlock x:Name="PrivacyStatementTextBlock" Margin="12,0,12,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

As you can see I just set ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility property to Auto and it scrolls down perfectly.

Try it out and let us know....

reagards,

Comment: The problem still remains, although the scrolling down action may be performed now, it does not scroll down to the end of the text file. Also, the text is extended outside of the page limits? I've also tried changing the height of the scrollviewer but that had no effect either?